# Django - url with variable (slug)

Tags: django

This is my template file:

```
{% for tag, count in tags.items %}
     <a href="{% url 'tags'  slug=tag.slug  %}">{{ tag }}</a> ({{count}}),
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.tags, name='tags'),
```

I am trying to take {{ tag }} as slug parameter. Is it possible? Next I would try to create page where I will list all pages that cointain tag in keywords field in Sites model.

I don't have tag model by the way. I am trying to take my tag variable and put it into my url (tag/tagvariable).

I get tags that way:
index.view

```
tags = Tags().all_tags()
context['tags'] = tags
```

calculations.py

```
class Tags():

    def all_tags(self):
        sites = Site.objects.values('keywords')
        keywords = []
        tags = []
        for site in sites:
            keywords.append(site['keywords'].split(','))
        for keyword in keywords:
            for tag in keyword:
                tags.append(tag.strip())
        return(dict(Counter(tags)))
```

models.py

```
class Site(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
        'Subcategory',
        chained_field='category',
        chained_model_field='category',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    keywords = MyTextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    url = models.URLField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "%s/%i" % (self.subcategory.slug, self.id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Strony"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: can you show us your tag model ?

Comment: I explained it a little bit above. Excuse me for my poor english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A tag model is going to make your life easier**
I'm assuming that you've make the correct view tag, use the [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) tag to convert your tag to a slug

```
{% for tag, count in tags.items %}
     <a href="{% url "tags"  tag|slugify  %}">{{ tag }}</a> ({{count}}),
{% endfor %}
```

and in the urls.py

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.tags, name='tags'),
```

Comment: Great solution. Now my url looks like it should:) Is it possible to revert this tag in simply way? For example 'modern-talking' back to 'modern talking'?

Comment: try with [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) 'modern-talking'.replace('-', '') => 'modern talking'

Comment: if your tag contain - than your going to have some problems